# Unable to use the method courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.return() in Google Classroom API

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-api-python-client, google-classroom

I am trying to return the responses received in [Google Classroom](https://classroom.google.com), according to the API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/return) on this, I need to use this method `courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.return()` but this triggers an error because of the keyword `return` being used as a funtion call.

Please correct me if I'm wrong and any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can find the documentation of the method in Python [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/classroom/v1/python/latest/classroom_v1.courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.html#return_)

So the request should look like

```
service().courseWork().studentSubmissions().return_(courseId=PASS_HERE_THE_COURSEID, courseWorkId=PASS_HERE_THE_COURSEWORDID, id=PASS_HERE_THE_SUBMISSION_ID)
```

Please keep in mind that:

> Only a teacher of the course that contains the requested student submission may call this method.

Comment: I am aware of that, but my error is with using it, the keyword `return` is causing the problem

Comment: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` and how can you use the keyword `return` like that? It is used for returning values from a function.

Comment: Sorry for the typo - it is `return_` with underscore - this should give you syntax errors!

Comment: Thanks a lot! The documentation that I was referring to (on developers.google.com) had it written like this `retu...` and upon copying, it copied only `return` and so was my doubt, thanks again for clarifying.